# Visual Studio 2010 (win 7 x64) Selenium Unit Test Keeps Pending

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, selenium, nuget

I am trying for several hours to make a Unit Testing with Selenium driver for a custom website. The problem is, my first test case is always pending. I haven't written any other. I tried several different tutorials, but none works. What I have done:

- Install Selenium WebDriver through NuGet Console (have a reference);
- Install Selenium WebDriver.Support through NuGet (have a reference);
- I have even turned the firewall off;

Lastly, I am following the tutorial on this page [dotnet-developer.de](http://www.dotnet-developer.de/2012/11/vbnet/tips-and-tricks-for-selenium-webtests/)!  The tutorial does not work too. It is given in vb.net, but I have translated it in C# as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace FastMenuSeleniumTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for UnitTest1
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {

        public IWebDriver driver;
        const string BaseURL = "http://www.bing.com";

        public UnitTest1()
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        private TestContext testContextInstance;

        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }

        #region Additional test attributes
        //
        // You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
        //
        // Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
        // [ClassInitialize()]
        // public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) { }
        //
        // Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
        // [ClassCleanup()]
        // public static void MyClassCleanup() { }
        //
        // Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
        [TestInitialize()]
        public void TestInitialization() 
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
            //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
        }
        //
        // Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
        [TestCleanup()]
        public void TestCleanup() 
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        //
        #endregion

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            IWebElement SearchBox = default(IWebElement);
            IWebElement FirstResult = default(IWebElement);

            //Go to Bing Homepage
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseURL);

            //Get Handle for Searchbox
            SearchBox = GetWebElement(driver, By.Id("sb_form_q"), 10);

            //Enter Search Text
            SearchBox.SendKeys("dotnet-developer.de");

            //Different ways to start the search
            //Method 1: Press ENTER
            SearchBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            //Method 2: Grab Search-Button and click it
            //Dim SearchButton As IWebElement
            //SearchButton = GetWebElement(driver, By.Id("sb_form_go"), 10)
            //SearchButton.Click()

            //Now get the first result returned by Bing search
            FirstResult = GetWebElement(driver, By.XPath("//ul[@class='sb_results']/li/div/div/div/h3/a"), 10);

            //Method 1: Compare the subject
            string ExpectedText = "dotnet-developer.de | Tips for vb.net,…";
            Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedText, FirstResult.Text, "Subject is not correct");

            //Method 2: Compare the link
            string ExpectedURL = "http://www.dotnet-developer.de/";
            Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedURL, FirstResult.GetAttribute("href"), "URL is not correct!");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve Web Element using default driver and default timeout
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="definition">Definition of the WebElement to grab</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <remarks></remarks>
        private IWebElement GetWebElement(OpenQA.Selenium.By definition)
        {
            const int DefaultTimeout = 10;
            return GetWebElement(definition, DefaultTimeout);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve Web Element using default driver
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="definition">Definition of the WebElement to grab</param>
        /// <param name="timeoutSeconds">Seconds to wait until a timeout is thrown</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <remarks></remarks>
        private IWebElement GetWebElement(OpenQA.Selenium.By definition, int timeoutSeconds)
        {
            return GetWebElement(driver, definition, timeoutSeconds);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Waits until the given element is enabled and visible
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="webDriver"></param>
        /// <param name="definition"></param>
        /// <param name="seconds"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <remarks>Needs to wait for .displayed because for e.g. in a collapsed Treeview all nodes are available but not visible 
        /// if the parent node is collapsed and therefore the following error would appear:
        /// OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
        /// </remarks>
        private IWebElement GetWebElement(IWebDriver webDriver, OpenQA.Selenium.By definition, int seconds)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));

            wait.Until(d => { return d.FindElement(definition).Enabled & d.FindElement(definition).Displayed; });

            return webDriver.FindElement(definition);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have identified the problem myself. First of all, I have to be more specific about the software on my machine. I have installed both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 on my PC. I was trying to make the tests in Visual Studio 2010, but they were pending. When I opened the tests in VS 2012, all run fine and I had no problem. It seems both VS mess up something (which I am not aware of) and I need to use the later version.

Comment: Thought you are wrong and something not about compatibility issues must have been the real cause, until I came across [to this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/09/08/not-able-to-run-unit-tests-when-visual-studio-2010-and-visual-studio-2012-are-installed-side-by-side.aspx) which proves that you are correct.

Comment: I am having this same problem with VS2017. I have VS2015 on this machine but have rarely ever used it. Any thoughts on why I'm still getting the same issue?

Comment: @DanCsharpster I cannot tell you the current reason, maybe if you could provide whatever you see in the output window. However, ReSharper could be able to run them. For example, you could run nUnit tests with ReShaper, without the need to install nUnit extension in Visual Studio. I currently have both VS2015 and VS2017 and the tests are running on my machine in both versions. You could also try running them in the console with MSTest or dotnet, depending if they are .net or netcore; worst case scenario, it will output some message why they cannot run.

Comment: @Nikola, thanks for the suggestions! I was able to fix it. I updated the NUnit  and NUnit3Adapter packages and then upgraded Resharper to the latest version. Then everything worked perfectly!